# VB DataGridView add items to DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview with informations of employees,
I want to show the teams of every employee in a comboboxcell

the MsgBox is working fine and showing the employee(collab) with his Teams(Equipe)
but I have a problem in adding the teams to the cell
It added all the teams in every row
and clear() was not resolving the problem
it can be with using DataGridViewComboBoxCell but I can't find what is missing 
here is the code:

```
  Try
        Conn.Open()
        Dim i As Integer

        DataGridView2.ReadOnly = False
        For i = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim collab As String = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("RefDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value
            Dim query As String = "Select Label From equipe_collab where ref_collab='" + collab + "'"
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, Conn)
            Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Poles") 

            Do While dr.Read = True

                MsgBox("collab :" + collab + "| Equipe :" + dr.Item(0))

               ' Poles.Items.Add(dr.Item(0)) '

                cell.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))

            Loop

        Next i
        Conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Thank you

Comment: The items of DataGridViewComboBox columns are the same for all rows. Restricting the choice for specific rows is quite complicated. Is it your intent?

Comment: The problem is to add different values to every combobox in datagrid rows  from a databse request (eg row 1: Emp X -- Name X - teams(A/B/D)|row2 : Emp Y-- Name Y--teams(C/D))  teams is the combobox with values from sql command

Comment: You must then handle the RowEnter event in order to reinitialize the  DataGriidViewComboBoxColumn.Items with the appropriate values.

Comment: How ? can you suggest the code modification Plz, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skeletton of the rowEnter eventhandler used to update the DatagridView ComboBox items (C# code):

```
private void DataGridView2_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // get here the row values to be used to determine the ComboBox content
    // Adapt the 2 following lines
    int    col1Value = (int   )dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["col1Name"].Value ;
    string col2Value = (string)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["col2Name"].Value ;

    List<string> PoleValues = new List<String>() ;
    // Here, your code to add to PoleValues the ComboBox values from colXValues
    ...  

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)DatagridView2.Columns["RefDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"] ;
    cb.Items.clear() ;
    cb.Items.AddRange(PoleValues) ;
}
```

Automatic conversion of above code to vb.net:

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    ' get here the row values to be used to determine the ComboBox content
    ' Adapt the 2 following lines
    Dim col1Value As Integer = CInt(dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("col1Name").Value)
    Dim col2Value As String = DirectCast(dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("col2Name").Value, String)

    Dim PoleValues As List(Of String) = New List(Of [String])()
    ' Here, your code to add to PoleValues the ComboBox values from colXValues
    ' ...  

    Dim cb As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = DirectCast(DatagridView2.Columns("RefDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
    cb.Items.clear()
    cb.Items.AddRange(PoleValues)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it is not working , we should have 2 loops one for the rows and the second for comobobox cell  items

Comment: As I told you previously, All ComboBox items are the same. So, the only solution is to modify items list each time you enter a row. Therefore, looping on rows is useless. For the second loop on cells, do you mean that on the same row, you have many data comboboxes using the same list of values.

Comment: no different values of same combobox in every row, can you suggest the VB code with filling the list with the sql cmd ?

Answer (score 1):

try this..

First set your datagridview2 "readonly" property to "False"

Then u can add items in this way

Dim combocell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell 
combocell = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells("Poles")
combocell.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried that but it is not working

Comment: mmm...strange. i just tried your code (just a little bit simplified) and it works!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that  `Poles.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))` (CBcolumn) is working but with adding all the items in all rows

and      `cell.Items.Add(dr.Item(0))` is not working

Answer (score 0):

Graffito
I want to add items to combobox (col 2) using the ref of collab (col1 = textbox) in the same line 
         so I will not convert the same column from textbox to columnbox

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    ' get here the row values to be used to determine the ComboBox content
    ' Adapt the 2 following lines
    Dim col1Value As Integer = CInt(DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("col1Name").Value)
    Dim collab As String = DirectCast(DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("RefDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value, String)

    Dim PoleValues As List(Of String) = New List(Of [String])()
    ' Here, your code to add to PoleValues the ComboBox values from colXValues
    ' ...  
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        Dim query As String = "Select Label From equipe_collab where ref_collab='" + collab + "'"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, Conn)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Do While dr.Read = True
            PoleValues.Add(dr.Item(0))
        Loop
        Conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    '
    ' I want to add items to combobox(col 2) using the ref of collab (col1) in thee same line 
    '  so I will not convert the same column from textbox to columnbox
    ' 
    Dim cb As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = DirectCast(DataGridView2.Columns("RefDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)

    cb.Items.Clear()
    cb.Items.AddRange(PoleValues)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    //Insert 3 rows
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()

    //set ReadOnly = False
    DataGridView1.ReadOnly = False


    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Poles")

        //insert values 1,2,3 in first row and set selected value of combobox
        If i = 0 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = "Employ1"
            cell.Items.Add("1")
            cell.Items.Add("2")
            cell.Items.Add("3")

            cell.Value = cell.Items(0)
        End If

        //insert values 4,5,6 in first row and set selected value of combobox
        If i = 1 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = "Employ2"
            cell.Items.Add("4")
            cell.Items.Add("5")
            cell.Items.Add("6")

            cell.Value = cell.Items(0)
        End If

        //insert values 7,8,9 in first row and set selected value of combobox
        If i = 2 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = "Employ3"
            cell.Items.Add("7")
            cell.Items.Add("8")
            cell.Items.Add("9")

            cell.Value = cell.Items(0)
        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Gennaro, your code is working alone, but it is not working with   datagrid  loaded by DataSet

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works :D

Both of you Graffito and Gennaro helped me to get it

Here the code:

```
Private Sub dataGridView2_RowEnter(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
Handles DataGridView2.RowEnter

    Dim collab As String = DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("RefDataGridViewTextBoxColumn").Value
    Dim cell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Poles")
    Try
        Conn.Open()
        Dim query As String = "Select Label From equipe_collab where ref_collab ='" + collab + "'  "
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, Conn)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        cell.Items.Clear()
        Do While dr.Read = True
            cell.Items.AddRange(dr.Item(0))
        Loop

        cell.Value = cell.Items(0)

        Conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```